# if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is nondecreasing at every point of $[a,b]$ then $f$ is nondecreasing in $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise 51 of chapter 5 of Curso de análise vol.1 (Elon Lages Lima). A function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is nondecreasing at a point $a \in X$ if there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y \in X$ with $a-\delta < x \leq a \leq y<a+\delta$, we have  $f(x)\leq f(a)\leq f(y)$.

Show that:

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$  is nondecreasing at every point of $[a,b]$ then $f$ is nondecreasing in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? What tools do you have?

Comment: use compactness of $[a,b]$

Comment: @VictorDanielMendozaRubio is this false in $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: perhaps connectedness also plays a role. Take $p<q$ find $\delta_p$ that works for $a=p$, then find another $\delta$ that works for $a=p+\delta_p$, try to cover the interval $[p,q]$ this way. This is a standard type argument, building a subset of $[p,q]$ that contains $p$ and is both open and closed, hence equals $[p,q]$.

Comment: @Mirko that is almost a proof: the only detail is: if the sequence of $\delta_p$ found is such that $\sum \delta_p < b-a$ then...

Comment: this exercise if of the book Curso de análise vol.1 (Elon Lages Lima). Is the exercise  51 of chapter 5.

Comment: @dcolazin There are two options (a) continue transfinitely, or (b) call a point $r$ (with $p\le r\le q$) good if $f$ is non-decreasing on $[p,r]$ and prove there is no largest good point apart from $q$. There are some details yet, since non-decreasing at $a$ doesn't obviously imply non-decreasing in a neighborhood of $a$, this may need some work on its own.

Comment: use compactness of $[a,b]$. Given two points $x,y \in [a,b]$ with $x\leq y$, we must show that $f(x) \leq f(y)$. As $f$ is nondecreasing at every point of $[a,b]$, then in particular is nondecreasing at every point of $[x,y]$.

Comment: Then for all $\alpha \in [x,y]$, exist $I_{\alpha}=(\alpha-\delta_{\alpha}, \alpha+\delta_{\alpha} )$ such that  for all $c,d \in I_\alpha$ with $c\leq \alpha \leq d$, we have $f(c)\leq f(\alpha)\leq f(d)$.

Comment: Is clear that $[x,y]\cup_{\alpha \in [x,y]} I_{\alpha}$.

Comment: By compactness of $[a,b]$, exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdot,\alpha_n$ such that $[x,y]\subset I_{\alpha_1} \cup I_{\alpha_2} \cdots \cup I_{\alpha_n}$.

Comment: There I stayed. How can I conclude from this that $ f (x) \leq f (y) $.

Comment: This is based on completeness of real numbers. See one proof based on Dedekind's theorem in my blog post https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/monotone-functions-part-1.html?m=0

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that serves as an example of *real induction*, a technique for proving statements indexed by a real interval (somewhat analogous to standard induction for statements indexed by the natural numbers):

Following the notation Pete Clark uses [**here**](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/realinduction.pdf), we let $S \subset [a,b]$ be the largest interval whose left endpoint is at $a$ on which $f$ nondecreases globally$^\dagger$.  We wish to show that $S = [a,b]$, which is equivalent to showing that $S$ is an inductive set$^\ddagger$.  Per the definition, we need to demonstrate three things to conclude that $S$ is inductive:

$\qquad \qquad \bullet \quad a \in S$

$\qquad \qquad \bullet \quad$ If $a \leq x < b$, then $x \in S \implies [x,y] \subset S$ for some $y > x$

$\qquad \qquad \bullet \quad$ If $a < x \leq b$ and $[a,x) \subset S$, then $x \in S$

To start, we must have $a \in S$ since $f$ is nondecreasing at $a$; so there is some neighborhood around $a$ on which $f$ nondecreases globally.  In the same vein, if we have $x \in S$ for some $a \leq x < b$, then because the function is nondecreasing at $x$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x \! - \! \delta, \ x \! + \! \delta) \subset S$.  Note that this interval—on which $f$ is nondecreasing—shares intersection with the interval $[a,x]$ on which $f$ is globally nondecreasing.  Hence, $f$ must be globally nondecreasing on $[a, x \! + \! \delta)$; i.e. $[a, x \! + \! \delta) \subset S$.  From here, of course we can guarantee a $y > x$ such that $[x,y] \subset S$: simply take $y = x + \delta/2$.

Finally, suppose $[a,x) \subset S$.  First, let $U = (x \! - \! \varepsilon, \ x \! + \! \varepsilon)$, with $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough so that $f$ is nondecreasing on $U$; such an epsilon is guaranteed because $f$ nondecreases at $x$.  Since $f$ is nondecreasing on both $[a,x)$ and $U$ considered individually, and since $[a,x)$ and $U$ share an intersection, we must have $f$ nondecreasing globally on $U \cup V$; i.e. $U \cup V \subset S$.  In particular, $x \in S$.

We have shown that $S$ is an inductive set, from which we conclude $S = [a,b]$.

---

$^\dagger$When we say $f$ nondecreases "globally" on $S$, we are stressing for clarity that $w < z \implies f(w) \leq f(z)$ for all $w, z \in S$, *sans local condition*.

---

$^\ddagger$See Theorem $2$ in the linked paper.

Comment: @Victor Daniel Mendoza Rubio: For anyone interested in an overview of three related notions of "increasing" for a function, see [this 23 April 2006 ap-calculus post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4661014) archived at Math Forum.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing the non-decreasing at one point with the local non-decreasing.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that was a reserved term.  Everywhere I said "locally nondecreasing", I meant "decreasing at [the point]", and the argument should be fine as the definition given in the OP is what I had in mind.  Will edit.

Comment: $\text{Fixed!}$

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment as I'm not sure it works, but I'm short of the required 50 reputation points. It is an attempt to modify Mirko's original suggestion in the comments to ensure that $\sum \delta_p$ is sufficiently large. Apologies for the clumsy indexing and notation.

Let $x, z \in [a, b]$ with $x < z$. For each $y \in [x, z]$, form the neighborhood $B(\delta_y, y)$ where $\delta_y$ is the supremum over all $\delta$ provided for $y$ in the hypothesis. Then the balls $B(\delta_y, y)$ form an open cover of $[x, z]$, so since $[x, z]$ is compact, there is a finite subcover,
$$
\{B(\delta_{y_1}, y_1), \dots, B(\delta_{y_n}, y_n)\}.
$$

WLOG, we may assume that $y_{i} < y_{i + 1}$ and that $B(\delta_{y_i}, y_i) \not \subset B(\delta_{y_j}, y_j)$ for $y \neq j$. By examining the possible ways that consecutive neighborhoods can overlap* (two of which are pictured below), we conclude
$$
f(x) = f(y_0) \leq f(y_1) \leq \cdots \leq f(y_{n+1}) = f(z)
$$
so that $f$ is non-decreasing on $[a, b]$.
[image]
<sub>* In the top case pictured, $y_i < y_{i+1} < y_{i} + \delta_{y_i}$ so $f(y_i) \leq f(y_{i+1})$. In the bottom case, $y_i < z < y_{i + \delta_i}$ so $f(y_i) \leq f(z)$. On the other hand, $y_{i + 1} - \delta_{y_{i + 1}} < z < y_{i + 1}$ so $f(z) \leq f(y_{i + 1})$. Thus, $f(y_{i}) \leq f(z) \leq f(y_{i + 1})$. Etc. I'm pretty sure that in every case, we can deduce $f(y_i) \leq f(y_{i + 1})$</sub>

Comment: @VictorDanielMendozaRubio Sorry, what do you mean by  “non-presence”?

Comment: Sorry, traslation error. It seems to me that you are confusing the non-decreasing at one point with the local non-decreasing.

Comment: @VictorDanielMendozaRubio I edited my answer and included an image to attempt clarification. Let me know what you think. As far as I can tell, I haven't confused non-decreasing at one point with local nondecreasing. (Like Kaj, when I had used the term "local nondecreasing" in previous versions, I meant "nondecreasing at one point." I see why that isn't a good choice now).